# Linq expression .Any(List<string>)

Tags: c#, linq

I have an List containting (among other things) Remark1, Remark2 and Remark3. I'd like to make sure that only valid remarks are written in these fields. Today I check it like this:

```
foreach (GradeRow row in Grade.GradeRows)
{
    if (!(okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark1) && okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark2) && okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark3)))
    {
        FailedCourseCodes.Add(row.CourseCode);
    }
}
```

Is there a Linq expression that can do something like .Contains(List)?

Comment: Would benefit us if you also posted a sample of your class structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still have to check each field individually but you can eliminate the loop:

```
FailedCourseCodes.Add(
    Grade.GradeRows.Where(row=>
        okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark1) && 
        okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark2) && 
        okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark3)
        )
);
```

You *could* make it slightly shorter by creating an array from the fields:

```
FailedCourseCodes.Add(
    Grade.GradeRows.Where(row=>
        (new [] {row.Remark1, row.Remark2, row.Remark3})
            .Except(okRemarks).Any()
        )
);
```

but that's significantly harder to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will return all rows that contain a bad remark:

```
 Grade.GradeRows.Where( row => new string[]{row.Remark1, row.Remark2, Row.Remark3}.Any ( remark => !okRemarks.Any(remark)))
```

Answer (score 0):

.Intersect( IEnumerable ) and then comparing the result's Count() is the only option I can think of. Something in the lines of:

```
foreach( var failedGrade in Grade.GradeRows
                                  .Select( x => new String[]{ row.Remark1, row.Remark2, row.Remark3 } )
                                  .Where( remarks => remarks.Intersect( okRemarks ).Count() < remarks.Length ) )
{
    FailedCourseCodes.Add(failedGrade.CourseCode);
}
```

@d-Stanley got it right, but did not add the results correctly

```
foreach( var failedGrade in Grade.GradeRows.Where( row => !(
                                                okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark1) &&
                                                okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark2) &&
                                                okRemarks.Contains(row.Remark3) ) ) )
{
    FailedCourseCodes.Add(failedGrade.CourseCode);
}
```